# Proof of a limit inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification

Prove that if $a, b \in \mathbb R$ and $a \le x_n \le b$ for all $n \in \mathbb N^+$ and $(x_n)$ converges, then $a \le lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \le b$.

Is the following proof valid? For this proof I used the following lemma:
If $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are convergent and $x_n \ge y_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N^+$, then $lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \ge lim_{n \to \infty} y_n$.

**Proof**
Let $(x_a)$ be the constant sequence $(a, a, \ldots)$ and $(x_b)$ be the constant sequence $(b, b, \ldots)$.
Then, for all $n \in \mathbb N^+, a \le x_n \le b \implies x_a \le x_n \le x_b $.
Note that $x_a \to a$ and $x_b \to b$.
Therefore from the above lemma we have $lim_{n \to \infty} x_a \le lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \le lim_{n \to \infty} x_b \iff a \le lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \le b$.

Comment: it's fine for me.

Comment: It is correct.  You could skip the definition of $x_a$ and $x_b$ as they are not needed.

Comment: It is OK if the lemma has been proved in your course and this is a subsequent homework problem.

Comment: @Dirk Could you explain why they are not needed?

Comment: Just to make the writeup of the proof more crisp... The logical structure is totally OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Another Easy Proof:(without using theorem)**

Since $(x_n)$ converges, there exists $l\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}x_n=l$. That is for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $n_\epsilon\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for each $n>n_\epsilon$, $|x_n-l|<\epsilon \Rightarrow $ for each $n>n_\epsilon$, $l-\epsilon<x_n<l+\epsilon \Rightarrow$  for each $n>n_\epsilon$, $l<x_n+\epsilon \le b+\epsilon$ and $a\le x_n<l+\epsilon \Rightarrow$ $l\le b$ and $a\le l$.

Therefore $a\le \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}x_n \le b$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = L < a$:

Case $1$: $x_n < L$ for some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$:   $x_{n_0} - a = x_{n_0} - L + L - a < 0+0=0$, contradiction to $x_n \geq a, \forall n$.

Case $2$: $x_n \geq L, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$: then choose $\epsilon = a-L > 0 \Rightarrow \exists n_{0}: x_{n_0} - L < a-L \Rightarrow x_{n_0} < a$, contradiction again.

Thus: $L \geq a$.